# Using several Eval("Variable") in a repeater for imageurl

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get several values into an imageurl by using a repeater and Eval.

This is what I've got now:

```
ImageUrl='/images/<%# Eval("OneId") %> + "/" + <%# Eval("TwoId") %> + "." + <%# Eval("Extension")%>'
```

This is what the url becomes:

```
 img src="/images/&lt;%#%20Eval(&quot;CarId&quot;)%20%&gt;%20+%20&quot;/&quot;%20+%20&lt;%#%20Eval(&quot;ImageId&quot;)%20%&gt;%20+%20&quot;.&quot;%20+%20&lt;%#%20Eval(&quot;Extension&quot;)%&gt;">`
```

And this is what i would like to get out: *`/images/4578/123478.png`*

Anyone know how I should do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work and make your code more readable

```
ImageUrl=<%# String.Format("'/images/{0}/{1}.{2}'", Eval("OneId"), Eval("TwoId"), Eval("Extension")) %>
```